# where is in journal3 (template for opencart) iframe? And how can I changing it?

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3, journal, opencart-events

I was look for .twig file or section in admin panel but did`nt find nothing.
I want to change layout in this iframe.
OpenCart version 3 on the twig. 
This`s button for call iframe:

```
<a class="btn btn-cart" 
data-toggle="tooltip" 
data-tooltip-class="module-products-27 
module-products-grid cart-tooltip"
data-placement="top"
onclick="cart.add('360', $(this).closest('.product-thumb').find('.button-group 
 input[name=\'quantity\']').val());" 
data-loading-text="<span class='btn-text'>Buy</span>" 
data-original-title="Buy"><span class="btn-text">Buy</span>
</a>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? This is not `iframe`. It's just adding to a cart button.   And do you have a link on a live site?

Comment: http://shoploft.swipe-time.com - button on the products miniature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you whant replace text, icon and style:

Cart button text you will find in language file **catalog/language/en-gb/en-gb.php**, line

```
$_['button_cart']           = 'Add to Cart';
```

**PRODUCT PAGE**

Icon and setting of this button you will find in

**Journal > Styles > Product Page > DEFAULT**

On this setting page find **Buttons > Add to Cart**

**PRODUCT GRID**

Icon and setting of this button you will find in

**Journal > Styles > Product Grid > DEFAULT**

On this setting page find **Buttons Group > Add to Cart**